# Recursively get the type of property in a generic recursive type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am currently trying to create a type that transforms an interface into a special array type for better auto completion.

This is currently what I have.

```
type UnStyleKey<K extends PropertyKey> = K extends `${infer P}Style` ? Uncapitalize<P> : K;

interface ComponentMap<T = unknown> {
  key: UnStyleKey<keyof T>;
  subKeys?: Array<ComponentMap<T>>;
  prefix?: string;
}
```

An example would be:

```
interface TextInputStyle {
  mainContainerStyle: IOStyle<ContainerStyleProps, TextInputRestProps>;
  inputContainerStyle: IOStyle<ContainerStyleProps, TextInputRestProps>;
  iconStyle: IOStyle<IconStyleProps, TextInputRestProps>;
  clearIconStyle: Partial<IconButtonStyle>;
  inputStyle: IOStyle<InputStyleProps, TextInputRestProps>;
  fieldMessageStyle: FieldMessageStyle;
}

interface AutoCompleteStyle {
  mainContainerStyle: IOStyle<ContainerStyleProps, AutoCompleteRestProps>;
  textInputStyle: Partial<TextInputStyle>;
  autoCompleteItemsContainerStyle: IOStyle<ContainerStyleProps, AutoCompleteRestProps>;
  autoCompleteItemStyle: Partial<AutoCompleteItemStyle>;
  loadingTypographyStyle: IOStyle<TypographyStyleProps, AutoCompleteRestProps>;
  noOptionsTypographyStyle: IOStyle<TypographyStyleProps, AutoCompleteRestProps>;
}
```

I currently get auto completion for the first level properties. I can't infer the type to have correct auto completion for the `textInputStyle` type keys. My question is how can the `subKeys` get correctly typed for the nested interfaces.

EDIT:

In addition if possible I would like to have all Partial types as Required.
Playground link: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WmdSnDZ8NKgtNR3IXvZRy8BRAYsJX+o7gM7Nh9qtHY7nfbzUn9EcjUWR0Zjq7X68gsPDByi0Rj2xCBTbhaLxZKIEQ46klXAs2qST3NlhhLIYqeO1AiIQoxnaTXGJP-JGu8BF58tGKJbRelKIDKijIfdkyPVNUk-dcfzAP8ALlcdHwbNdv1-Td-1ld9UmyLQSDBPxjVNdlOVA4tUlmTwwDrfoyDwlk2XNYj835HUgSgCDkOg1Cnn6QYRjAKwuJeN4wCwJCNy3BkWAAbQAXUCSTPmEKBdisAByXdgOkFSoDPBSlLWKAVOvYBbzFFSYjOC5MDIKxJOEZSDPUlVs2oFSzySeyVKpANUFc6SdNSRSPLYsS0MAjSXO0qJdKCr8QtgszTnOS4bLs-S1ITJyD1c88PK8l0fLc1KQFU5kTTooieV8yLorSrCcLgUEaLKs0QC0-ykj04qDLIijRCopqCI5Nqouk6wgA)

Comment: Can you please create a ts playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: please include a playground with desired input/output

Comment: I have updated the question with the playground link @wonderflame

Comment: @AlexanderPol I'm not sure why sometimes the subkeys are without style and sometimes with. Here is the [link](https://tsplay.dev/Nroj5m) to my approach

Comment: @wonderflame thanks for the link with your solution, though this is not working after 3rd level nesting for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Comment: you didn't mention the depth, which is why I only did it for the second level. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX0y8w)

Comment: @wonderflame your last solution for some reason directly inherits  the iCss and iColorTheme of the IOStyle interface for items in the subKeys array.